# Adding to a list of pairs c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add to a list of pairs.
I have initialised the list as follows

```
 public List<Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, int>>> StudentRecords = new List<Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>();
```

I am creating a method to add to this list but it comes up with an error saying:

> No overload for method Add, takes 2 arguments

```
public void AddRecord(string studentname, Dictionary <string, int> studentMarks)
{
    StudentRecords.Add(studentname, studentMarks);
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, you have a list of `Tuple`, but you're not adding a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StudentRecords` is a `List` of `Tuple`. So you must add a `Tuple` like this

```
StudentRecords.Add(Tuple.Create(studentname, studentMarks));
```